# safe usage of iterators in multithreaded applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator

Say we have a data structure protected by a lock.

Now, Thread1 carries out these statements(say in function block X):

```
mGeoCodeVectorLock.lock();

auto it = std::find(mGeoCodeVector.begin(), mGeoCodeVector.end(), tokenName); 
if(it != mGeoCodeVector.end()) {        
         mGeoCodeVector.erase(it);        
}
mGeoCodeVectorLock.unlock();
```

And then Thread2 executes these statements(say in another function block Y):

```
auto iter = std::find(mGeoCodeVector.begin(), mGeoCodeVector.end(), tokenName); 

    mGeoCodeVectorLock.lock();


    if(it != mGeoCodeVector.end()) {        
             mGeoCodeVector.erase(it);        
    }
    mGeoCodeVectorLock.unlock();
```

Now, The way I see it:

1) If thread1 gets the lock in function block X and manages to erase the vector, then , the thread already holding an iterator and waiting on lock in function block Y ends up with an invalidated iterator since the container size has been changed by thread1.

2) So, the easy way to fix it would be i guess, to take all your iterators only once you manage to get hold of lock.

Are there some general principles/idioms of safe iterator usage, especially with regards to multi threaded applications?

Comment: I wouldn't bother using locks at all in that scenario.  What you need to do is logically split the work between the threads by copying the part of the data structure each thread wants to work on rather than sharing a vector between them.  Then copying back the result when it's done.  Anything else is just asking for pain and suffering.  Your algorithm may also spend most of its time spinning waiting for a lock, so MT will be pointless otherwise.

Comment: The whole point of locking is to make sure a shared resource is in a consistent state. If you have such a requirement then it follows that accessing the resource (including holding iterators) when it's not locked is dangerous.

Comment: it's a bunch of geoCodes that are stored in a class..and when we are done with processing, we need to erase it..copying and then updating back into the same data structure will again lead to contention

Comment: @Jonathan: yes agreed.Hence, the code is clearly flawed(legacy code).But i just wanted to know some idioms wrt iterator usage...RAII makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1. Lock the resource
2. create the iterators
3. mutate or query the resource
4. throw away the iterators
5. unlock the resource.

of course, using RAII in the implementation of the lock automates 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

What is your structure, is it a true vector or a list? If it is a vector, you have to aquire the lock before doing find. However, if it is a list (or can be made a list) removing from the list doesn't invalidate any iterators other than to the object being removed, so as long as token name is different, no locks are required.

Comment: agreed with observation.the question is not really about invalidation..it is about proper usage/idioms when it comes to iterators in multi threaded app